# Does the energy-momentum relation showcase the "magnitude", in the vectorial sense, of the energy?

Tags: special-relativity, energy, momentum, mass-energy, invariants

The energy-momentum relation is:

$$E^2=(mc^2)^2+(pc)^2 \rightarrow E=\sqrt{(mc^2)^2+(pc)^2}$$

Which is obviously very similar to the magnitude of a vector: $|\textbf{v}|=\sqrt{v_1^2+v_2^2}$

This begs the question of the existence of an energy four-vector: $\textbf{E}=(pc,mc^2)$. Is there anything sort of correct here, or is it just a coincidence?

Comment: It's just coincidence , E is no vector.

Answer (score 3):

There isn't an energy four-vector, but the similarity is not a coincidence. What there is is a momentum four-vector,
$$p^\mu = \left(p^0,\ \boldsymbol{p}\right)=\left(E/c,\ \boldsymbol{p}\right)$$
whose Minkowski norm/magnitude equals the mass-squared. Namely
$$m c^2 = \left\Vert p \right\Vert^2 := \eta_{\mu\nu} p^\mu p^\nu = (p^0)^2-\left\vert\boldsymbol{p}\right\vert^2 =\left(\frac{E}{c}\right)^2 -\left\vert\boldsymbol{p}\right\vert^2,$$
with $\eta_{\mu\nu}=\mathrm{diag}(1,-1,-1,-1).$

That is, the energy-momentum relation *is* expressing the magnitude of a four-vector but it is the *Minkowski magnitude* of the *momentum* four-vector.